# Sort table in pandas by certain value in column

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to sort this table by "Departure date" and "Value" which I could by using: sort_values(["Departure date:", "Value"]), but the thing is that I need to sort only Wednesday's flights starting from cheapest.

When I print(type(Data["Departure date])) is says: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>, if that helps.

```
City        Departure date   Airline         Value
Podgorica   Sat 1 Jan        Ryanair         14.46
Managua     Wed 5 Jan        Ryanair         1699.05
Bucharest   Tue 11 Jan       Ryanair         38.24
Oslo        Wed 12 Jan       Ryanair         24.32
Istanbul    Wed 12 Jan       Ryanair         120.00
Kyiv        Wed 12 Jan       Windrose        227.43
```

I could maybe split Departure date and extract only days of week, sort and join them later but it looks like a lot of work.
I just recently started with python and pandas so any help is welcomed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't sorting by two columns the solution for you? Or do other dates need to stay in the same order?

```
data.sort_values(['Departure date', 'Value'])
```

Comment: hi, it sorts first fridays(list is larger, I only extracted where wednesdays are), I assume it's because letter "F" is 6th letter of alphabet and w is among last letters, so I could somehow extract last 4 rows but I want cheapest on wednesday and want code to be as short as possible

Comment: convert the date to datetime, that would do it I guess